# Ruby modules methods

Tags: ruby

I was going through an online tutorial on Ruby module extends where the teacher explains the code with this

```
module Tracking
  def create(name)
    object = new(name)
    instances.push(object) # note this line
    return object
  end

  def instances
    @instances ||= []
  end
end



class Customer
  extend Tracking

  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def to_s
    "[#{@name}]"
  end
end
```

This was the output

```
puts "Customer.instances: %s" % Customer.instances.inspect
puts "Customer.create: %s" % Customer.create("Jason")
puts "Customer.create: %s" % Customer.create("Kenneth")
puts "Customer.instances: %s" % Customer.instances.inspect

Output:

Customer.instances: [] 

Customer.create: [Jason]

Customer.create: [Kenneth]

Customer.instances: [#<Customer:0x007f2b23eabc08 @name="Jason">, #<Customer:0x007f2b23eabaf0 @name="Kenneth">]
```

I got an understanding on how `extends` works but what I dont get is this method

```
def create(name)
        object = new(name)
        instances.push(object)
        return object
end
```

Specifically the line, `instances.push(object)`

Shouldn't it be `@instances.push(object)`

`instances` is a method in the module, how can we `push` objects to methods, it is not an array, it contains an array.

What is going on?

*Please, I am new to Ruby, I will really appreciate simple answers.*

Answer (score 1):

`instances` returns `@instances` which is an array, that's why when you are `push`ing things inside it, you are pushing it in `@instances` (variable) and not `instances`(method) .

calling `instances` will create the `@instances` with blank array if not present and return it, thereby, giving you a placeholder to keep stuff in.

For your understanding, you can even do this:

```
module Tracking
  def create(name)
    object = new(name)
    @instances ||= [] # NOW note this line
    @instances.push(object) # using @instances
    return object
  end

  def instances
    @instances # just a getter now
  end
end



class Customer
  extend Tracking

  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def to_s
    "[#{@name}]"
  end
end


2.4.1 :098 > puts "Customer.instances: %s" % Customer.instances.inspect
Customer.instances: [#<Customer:0x007f9772187d40 @name="Jason">]
 => nil
2.4.1 :099 > puts "Customer.create: %s" % Customer.create("Jason")
Customer.create: [Jason]
 => nil
2.4.1 :100 > puts "Customer.create: %s" % Customer.create("Kenneth")
Customer.create: [Kenneth]
 => nil
2.4.1 :101 > puts "Customer.instances: %s" % Customer.instances.inspect
Customer.instances: [#<Customer:0x007f9772187d40 @name="Jason">, #<Customer:0x007f9772037080 @name="Jason">, #<Customer:0x007f977223d690 @name="Kenneth">]
```

Comment: Ok. So it means whatever method returns we can directly manipulate them as well, which means in the original code, I can also do, `i = instances; i.push(object);`. This is what is actually happening?

Comment: indeed. `i= instances` will hold the same reference of array

Comment: Got that. But why was I downvoted, I am learning? Was there something wrong with the question? I did made sure to read on How to ask questions.

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't downvote you. It's a fair question for a learner, and I appreciate that you came with the code, phrased the question correctly and had genuine curiosity about the internals. Personally, that's how I learnt it as well. Here, take my upvote on question; and keep up with learning ;)